# How to check if email was sent using smtp in python 3.7

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I'm using `smtplib` to send emails using `sendmail()` function, how to know if email was sent or not as the function doesn't return a response code

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('myemail@outlook.com', 'mypassword')
s.sendmail('myemail@outlook.com', 'theotheremail@domain.com', 'message')
s.quit()
```

Comment: The function *does* return stuff. https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail):

> This method will return normally if the mail is accepted for at least one recipient. Otherwise it will raise an exception. That is, if this method does not raise an exception, then someone should get your mail. If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused. Each entry contains a tuple of the SMTP error code and the accompanying error message sent by the server.

Comment: I tried to send to a valid email and it returned an empty dictionary, then I tried to send another mail to an invalid email, it also returned an empty dictionary and in my inbox I got the following message : "The address you sent your message to wasn't found at the destination domain. It might be misspelled or it might not exist." so I can not differentiate between both returns